# Render sign up form in Angular js blocked by authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement the simplest possible means of signing up for a service through my web app. The landing page for the app is a sign in page, on which there is a link to a sign up page. I can't seem to simply redirect to a sign in partial- I think it's being blocked by authentication. So I have included the sign up form in my index.html with the sign in form. I'm trying to figure out how to use ng-show to display the sign up form and hide the sign in form when the sign up button is clicked, but am having difficulty with it. Can anyone advise on how to do this, or if there is a better way?

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Application</title>
//Links to stylesheets here
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

//This is what the user sees when they navigate to the page

    <div ng-controller="SignInCtrl">
        <div ng-show="!isAuthenticated" ng-hide = "signup">
            <form class = "form-signin">

                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
            <br />
            <input type="text" ng-model="username">
            </div>

            <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" ng-model="password">
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
            <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click="signIn()">Sign In</button>

//This is the link to sign up
            <a ng-model = "signup">Sign Up</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

         <div ng-controller = "AccountNewController">
           <div ng-show = "signup">
             This is where my sign up form will appear when my signup button is clicked.
             </div>
        </div>      

//This part of index.html is only shown when a user has been authenticated

        <div ng-show="isAuthenticated">

            <div class="col-md-2">
 //Menu Bar code here
</div>   
<div class="col-md-10">

//Other app partials are rendered here

  <div ng-view></div>    
</div>

        </div>
    </div>

//Links to JS files here   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ng-show should work fine, probably an issue with your js code

Comment: I don't have any JS code for ng-show directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some places where your code seems to not make any sense to me

```
    <div ng-controller="SignInCtrl">
        <div ng-show="!isAuthenticated" ng-hide = "signup">
            <form class = "form-signin">
```

Why use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` when one do the exact flip of the other?

```
//This is the link to sign up
            <a ng-model = "signup">Sign Up</a>
```

An `ng-model` bound to an anchor?

---

I think you can solve this one by using only `ng-show`.

I could update the answer if you could provide a plnkr

---

**Edit:**
To have the DIV shown to not authenticated users AND "on demand" by clicking somewhere, you could something like this:

```
    <div ng-controller="SignInCtrl" ng-init="signup = false">
        <div ng-show="!isAuthenticated || signup">
            <form class = "form-signin">
```

This for a "click to signup"

```
//This is the link to sign up
            <button ng-click="signup = true">Sign Up</button>
```

Or this to toggle the signup DIV

```
//This is the link to sign up
            <button ng-click="signup = !signup">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: I need to show the signin div if the user is NOT authenticated (hence ng-show="!isAuthenticated") and I need to hide it when the user IS authenticated OR if the user clicks on sign up (hence ng-hide = "signup"). I was experimenting with ng-model to see if it would make the ng-show work as I had seen it in the example on the official angular documentation. I also tried ng-click but that hasn't worked either. Thanks, I'll work on a plnkr.

Comment: `ng-show` already do this. When the user is authenticated, isAuthenticated will be `true`, hence the flip of it will be `false`, and `ng-show = false` will hide the DIV. I'll update the answer for the click part

Comment: Thanks but that shows the signup div when I navigate to the page without having to click the sign up button..

Comment: I've also been trying to achieve this with ng-switch, would you have any suggestions for using that instead?

Comment: if !isAuthenticated gets evaluated to false, it's impossible that ng-show evaluates to true.  Did you see the `ng-init="signup=false"` part? Did you set this value to true somewhere else?
Try changing the variable